# How to create an alias to report url

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to create a alias for my report server.
By default when i deploy a report it goes to http://machinename:80/reportserver, instead i want it to be http://newname/reportserver.

Any help on solving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you create CNAME record in your DNS?